# Split data for every 15 mins timestamp and loop through it

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to perform some calculations based on 15 minutes of data.

I get data like this for a day:

```
let DayData = db.sensingresults.find({
"updatedAt": {
    "$gt": ISODate("2020-06-07T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "$lte": ISODate("2020-06-08T00:00:00.000Z")
}, "vitalSensing": {"$exists": 1}
}).sort({updatedAt: 1})
```

I have timestamp value for each record for `DayData`

I want to get data into any temporary array for the first 15 minutes and perform some calculations on it and save it to DB. 
Then empty temporary array and load with next 15 minutes data, perform some calculations on it and save to DB. and so on...

I know how to do calculations and save to DB part. 
But I need some guidance on how to get data for every 15mins in sequence and loop through it.

**more detailed explanation:** 
my Data always starts from midnight : 2020-06-07T00:00:00.000Z like this.

Here is my high level idea but not sure how to proceed with implementation:

first get data for first 15mins into an array

```
let tempArray = [];
tempArray.push(data for > 12.0 am to <=12.15) // after completing for loop on tempArray, come here and load next set of data. 

    for (let i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
        ... perform my calculation
        ... save to db
     }
```

then empty array tempArray = [] and load next set of data which is >12.15am to <=12.30 am.... and so on... and perform same operations as above (do some calculations and saving to DB)

I need to iterate this process on whole `DayData` in form of 15mins chunks.

Comment: Are you in browser or Node?

Comment: actually I need to convert this in shell script once tested in javascript. either way is fine for me

Comment: What is wrong with doing a do/while loop starting at 00:00 with each loop adding 15 minutes to the time? At the start of your loop, you use JS's Date object to create the start and end times for this loop, do the query, do the calculations, add 15 minutes to the timestamp and loop.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly (fetch row with date + 15 minutes), you could convert your date to unix time and add 15 minutes (900000 ms), then convert it back for your query.

```
let unixTime = Date.parse(ISOString) + 900000
let date = new Date(unixTime).toISOString()
```

Edit: You can output an array of all objects in an interval of 15 minutes by filtering:

```
tempArray = DayData.filter(e => Date.parse(e.updatedAt) % 900000 === 0).map(e => e)
```

Comment: please go through my question again, unfortunately answer is not helpful for me. Thanks

Comment: Elaborate then. Or do you want to execute a function every 15th minute?

Comment: no. so I have data. timestamp starts from midnight which is "2020-06-07T00:00:00.000Z" for example. now I want to get data from 12 am to <= 12.15 am and process my operations. then  > 12.15 am to <=12.30 and process operations.. and so on.. let me add some more details to question again.

Comment: please check my question again